# StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console on windows

Tags: logstash, log4j2

I am trying to run logstash on windows. [image]

using the following command -

```
logstash.bat -f D:\confignfig.txt --path.settings D:\Software\Elasticsearch\logstash-5.5.0\config\ -l LogstashLogs
```

But I get this error -

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console. WARNING: Could not
>   find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or
>   /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings.
>   Continuing using the defaults An unexpected error occurred! :error =>
>   bad URI(is not URI?):
>   file:///D:\Software\Elasticsearch\logstash-5.5.0\config" - 
>   LogstashLogs"/log4j2.properties, :backtrace =>
>   ["D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/uri/common.rb:176:in
>   split",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/uri/common.rb:210:in
>   parse",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/uri/common.rb:747:in
>   parse",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/1.9/uri/common.rb:994:in
>   URI",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:77:in
>   initialize", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in synchronize'",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:75:in
>   initialize",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:229:in
>   execute",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in
>   run",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:209:in
>   run",
>   "D:/Software/Elasticsearch/logstash-5.5.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in
>   run",
>   "D:\Software\Elasticsearch\logstash-5.5.0\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:71:in
>   (root)"]

Any idea what is going here? Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: As it is seen from error message it refers to D:\Software\Elasticsearch\logstash-5.5.0 howver on the screen-shot it is D:\Elasticsearch\logstash-5.5.0. There might be some misconfiguration in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running logstash from root folder fixed this. I don't know if this is known issue or not but if you run logstash from bin folder you might get 'ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found'

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue and is expected to get fixed in next logstash release , 5.6.0.

Pls refer: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-5-5-0-error-statuslogger-no-log4j2-configuration-file-found/92921 
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/7526